# copy file in a gui with checkboxes

Tags: powershell

i'm creating a gui in powershell for copying files. first i add a file with a button, next i choose the folder where to copy and then i want to copy. unfortunately the script says the file path is empty. how can i solve this problem? Furthermore, i want to add 2 functions.

- a warning if no checkbox is marked
- a text field next to the choose button where i can see the path from the file i want to copy

  ```
  $PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'ascii'
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

  #create form
  $form             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
  $form.Width       = 500
  $form.Height      = 300
  $form.MaximizeBox = $false

  #choose file button
  $Button          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
  $Button.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,50)
  $Button.Text     = "choose file"
  $Button.Add_Click({
  Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) {  
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) | Out-Null
  $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
  $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
  $OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.*)| *.*”
  $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
  $OpenFileDialog.filename
  } 

  $file = Get-FileName -initialDirectory “c:”
  })
  $form.Controls.Add($Button)

  #create checkbox1
  $checkBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
  $checkBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 100)
  $checkBox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
  $checkBox.Text     = "folder 1"
  $form.Controls.Add($checkBox)

  #create checkbox2
  $checkBox2          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
  $checkBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10, 150)
  $checkBox2.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,30)
  $checkBox2.Text     = "folder 2"
  $form.Controls.Add($checkBox2)

  #copy file button
  $Button2          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $Button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,200)
  $Button2.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,50)
  $Button2.Text     = "copy file"
  $Button2.Add_Click({    

  #checkbox1 action
  if ($checkBox.Checked -eq $true)
  {
  copy-item -Path $file -Destination "C:\folder 1"
  }

  #checkbox2 action
  if ($checkBox2.Checked -eq $true)
  {
  copy-item -Path $file -Destination "C:\folder 2"
  }

  })
  $form.Controls.Add($Button2)

  #end
  [void]$form.ShowDialog()
  ```

Comment: the file you couches is not a global variable you need to add $global:file in your code thad file variable is also outsite of code te usebale.

Comment: add line 26  $global:file = Get-FileName -initialDirectory “c:\”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of improvements to be suggested but let's focus on your questions:

The problem is that the scope of your **$file variable** is local to the **function Get-Filename**.
So when accessed from outside of the function, it is always null.

As stated in the comments, the **minimum modification for your script to work** is the change the following line (I would also suggest to declare it initially outside of the function, at global level for sake of clarity):

```
# From this
$file = Get-FileName -initialDirectory "c:"

# To this
$Global:file = Get-FileName -initialDirectory "c:"
```

To **add a textbox** with the choosen filename, proceed as for the other controls:

```
#Text box with choosen file name
$txtBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (180, 20)
$txtBox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$form.Controls.Add($txtBox)
```

And to update the text, add the following line **after setting the $Global:file variable**:

```
$Global:file = Get-FileName -initialDirectory "c:"
$txtBox.Text = $Global:file
```

Finally, a message can be displayed if you add the following code to your **$Button2.Add_Click** code:

```
#nothing checked
if(($checkBox.Checked -eq $false) -and ($checkBox.Checked -eq $false)) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("No CheckBox checked")
}
```

Comment: much appreciated. works like a charm